# Storing Key-Value pair in SQL table and then updating and retrieving

Tags: sql-server, database

In my application, I came across a database design where I need to consider the below points:

- User will enter some values against a keyword *(I want to store as a key value pair in database table — table will have column name "key" and "value".)*
- User can update the same key and its values at a later point of time *(it is difficult to update the same key once I have saved it because I have to figure out which key has been modified.)*

Please help me any other approach I can take to save the key value pair in database. And in future in updating the key name and its value can be tracked so that I can update the same.

**Example:**

A template has been defined. In this template, there are some unknown attributes, which should be updated by the client to execute it.

Let's say one attribute is "##**Path**##". Here path should be replaced by actual path.

Hence we have to figure out all these attributes from the template and to be shown in UI as table (key-> Path , Value -> [Empty Textbox]). User can put a value against this path. We have to save it for future use because user can re-trigger it.

But before re-triggering, he can change the key from "##**Path**##" to "##**ActualPath**##". In this case I need to find out "Actual path" is the updated name of "Path", which is quite difficult for me.

Comment: Why are you not using identity primary key column to identify record? Is it possible for you to add one extra column?

Comment: If the key is `price`, how are you going to have different values for the paper clips and the Rolls Royces that you sell?  On its own, key/value is not sufficient.

Comment: @DMayuri There are set up key and values against one template. Template Id will be matched against a template table which is many to one relation. If I will have a id against each key how can I identify which key name user modified because it will difficult to track each PK for every key-value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Let say the key name is Price. In future user has privilege to change the key name form "Price" to "Market Price" in the template. ( From template only I am retrieving the key  and then I am showing it in UI and then saving it with its value to DB. and later if the key name changed then I have to update the key name in db.)

Comment: You've not shown enough outline schema with example values for me to understand what you're doing, then.  In particular, it isn't clear how the key/value pair are stored in relation to the things they describe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have updated the query. I want to do the db design.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info — I'm sorry to report that your scenario is not even as clear as mud to me yet; it is more opaque and less comprehensible.  It must be bedtime here or something.  I don't understand what you've got a template of.  Is it a table schema?  A schema for a row?  Are you playing some sort of EAV ([entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) game?  But if that's what you're up to, note that there's an identifier for the entity which thus far you appear to be resisting.  Good night.

Answer (score 1):

It looks strait-forward to me; I mean I do not really understood what exactly is your problem. You answered your own question.

Create a table something like this:

```
KVPTable
    Key, VARCHAR(whatever), PrimaryKey
    Value, VARCHAR(whatever)
```

As `Key` is primary key, it will not allow duplicate entries. You can execute UPDATE statement against `Key` to update any or both the fields.

```
UPDATE KVPTable SET Key = 'newKey' WHERE Key = 'oldKey'
UPDATE KVPTable SET Key = 'newKey', Value = 'newValue' WHERE Key = 'oldKey'
UPDATE KVPTable SET Value = 'newValue' WHERE Key = 'key'
```

This will make sure only one record is updated. Before calling statement, you can execute another SELECT statement to check if new `Key` already exists. Even if you do not check it, exception will be thrown which you should catch.

Comment: I have modified my query with an example. Here it is difficult to track the "old key" and "new key" matching.

Comment: Do you have a set number of key/value pairs or are you populating your table indefinitely?  Will you be reusing old and new keys etc.?

Comment: @GrammatonCleric I don't have a set number of key/value pair. I am populating those at run time and showing it in UI as a table.